# Shifting a 2D array to the left loop

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array with values in it. Example below:

```
010101
101010
010101
```

I want to create a loop that shifts these values to the left like the example below.

```
101010
010101
101010
```

So the element that "falls off" goes back in to the end. I'm having a hard time solving this issue in code.

Anyone got any advice?

So far I have made it scroll but I have no clue how to get the elements that fall off to go back in.

This is what I have so far.

```
for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        if (!(row >= array.length) && !(col >= array[row].length - 1)) {
            array[row][col] = array[row][col + 1];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you don't have to use an array, you could use a LinkedList and just remove the first node and tacks it on the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the modulus operator:

```
arrayShifted[row][col] = array[row][(col + 1) % array[row].length];
```

Remove your condition check as well.  Also note, to avoid overwriting values, you'll need to store the results in a new array.

```
for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < array[row].length; col++) {
        arrayShifted[row][col] = array[row][(col + 1) % array[row].length]
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't put the elements that "fall off" back in. I just does what my example above did.

Comment: Thanks! Works great. Now i Have to decipher what this algorithm does exactly :p Cheers man!

Comment: @kunruh Yes, it will need to be put into a new array.

Comment: Whoops, deleted my comment when I saw he said it worked. Thought I mis-traced the logic! That works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full method that takes in a variable amount of spots to shift each row and properly handles copying the same elements as in the modulus approach.

```
public void shiftArray(int[][] array, int shift) {

    for (int row = 0; row < array.length; row++) {
        int rowLength = array[row].length;

        // keep shift within bounds of the array
        shift = shift % rowLength;

        // copy out elements that will "fall off"
        int[] tmp = new int[shift];
        for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++) {
            tmp[i] = array[row][i];
        }

        // shift like normal
        for (int col = 0; col < rowLength - shift; col++) {
            array[row][col] = array[row][col + shift];
        }

        // copy back the "fallen off" elements
        for (int i = 0; i < shift; i++) {
            array[row][i + (rowLength - shift)] = tmp[i];
        }
    }
}
```

---

Test Run

```
int[][] array = new int[][] {
    {0,1,0,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,0,1,0,1}
};

shiftArray(array, 1);

for (int[] row : array) {
    for (int col : row) {
        System.out.print(col);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

// 101010
// 010101
// 101010
```